# OpenMP and C99 data

Tags: c, openmp, c99

How does OpenMP deal with data declared inside a parallel section?  Before C99 I would use the private() clause to specify thread-local data, e.g.

```
int i, x;
#pragma omp parallel for private(x)
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
   x=i;
}
```

Now that C99 allows mixing of data and code, I prefer to declare variables just before using them.  Does declaring data within the scope of the loop guarantee it is thread-private?  For example, is the following valid?

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
   int x=i;
}
```

I tried adding private(x) just in case, but my compiler objects (probably since x isn't declared yet).

Comment: A quick search on google indicates that this is indeed true. C++ had this property all along.

Comment: btw: you're using a C99-style `for`-loop in your C90 example code...

Comment: And the supposedly C99 example is valid C90 as well. You can declare any variable at the beginning of any compound statement (`{...}` blocks) in ANSI C.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, I've fixed the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some variables, including those declared within a parallel construct, have data-sharing attributes that are predetermined (eg, you can't declare them `shared` or `private`).  Those are defined in section 2.9.1.1 in the OMP3 standard.

In this case, [OpenMP Standard 3.0](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/spec30.pdf), 2.9.1.1: (p78, line 12) "Variables with automatic storage duration that are declared in a scope inside the construct are private."   I'm pretty sure it's always been this way in OpenMP.   So yes, in your C99 example, i and x are private; on the other hand, I understand that same section to say that if x was declared static, it'd be shared.   I think in this respect, it more or less does what you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

C always allowed for the declaration of `x` inside the `for` block. so there is no difference at all, and you should have done that before.

The difference is in fact in the declaration of `i`. *This* in C89 you would have to have declare before the `for` loop.
 OMP then "knows" by itself that the loop variable must be local for each thread.

```
int i;
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
   int x=i;
}
```

Here C99 really eases your life and clarifies your code.

Comment: In this case, you actually wouldn't have had to add a `private(i)` - a loop variable "is implicitly made private in the loop construct. " (2.5.1, OpenMP 3 standard) as a shared loop variable in a parallel for wouldn't make any sense.